# Dont allow use of default constructor in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to create a class in C++ which forbids the use of the *default constructor*.
Nevertheless, I think I'm failing, or I'm not understanding what is happening behind the scenes. Here is what I have so far:

```
class Point {
public:
        float x;
        float y;
        Point(float newX, float newY); //Definition is irrelevant
        Point() = delete; //Default or "empty" constructor is forbidden, so deleted
}
/* ... */
int main(void)
{
        Point a(1, 2); //Ok, should be available
        Point b; //Ok, does not compile
        Point c(); //Not ok, it does compile :(
}
```

My intended behavior is for point c not to compile. I'd appreciate help in generating such a behavior, or if not possible, an explanation of why this works like that.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I got an answer in this prior thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40683637/how-to-create-a-c-11-non-default-constructible-allocator. Note that the posted code in the question was updated to show how to do this.

Comment: `c` is not an object. So the default c'tor isn't invoked, don't worry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is happening is a vexing parse. You're not declaring an object, but a function with name c and return type of class `Point`.

---

Declaring any constructor will prevent compiler from generating default constructor, so declaration with `=delete` is superflows.

---

### Aggregate initialization

If you know the order, you don't even need constructor:

```
Point p{newX, newY};
```

Will work just fine.

---

### Uniform initialization syntax

In the future, to avoid such cases, use `{}`:

```
Point p{}; //default constructs
```

Comment: While you may argue that the  `=delete` is superfluous, it can also be said that it serves as a comment that explicitly shows that the programmer intended for that constructor not to be created.

Comment: @TCD, I would also expect s comment why. In this case, it is pretty clear that default init will cause problems with uninitialized values.

Comment: A default constructor does not **have** to cause problems. In this case, the implicitly generated one could. You could write an explicit `Point() : x{0}, y{0}{}` as a default constructor. If you see just the overloaded constructor, then you can assume that the programmer probably didn't just forget to write a default constructor. But there is a chance that they didn't think about it and just forgot to add it. However, if you see it explicitly deleted, then you know that that was his intention.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
    Point c(); //Not ok, it does compile :(
```

Is not interpreted as creating an object c of type Point, it is interpreted as declaring a new function c which return a Point and takes no arguments. Look here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

There also no need for this line:

```
    Point() = delete; //Default or "empty" constructor is forbidden, so deleted
```

If you declare any constructor, then the default constructor is overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

It does compile, but only because it is not what you think it is. You correctly deleted the default constructor. Actually already declaring a non default constructor prevents the class from being default constructible:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(int);
}

Foo x; // wont compile
```

Declaring the default constructor as deleted is good practice as it explicitly states that the default constructor is left out on purpose.

Why did it compile?

```
Foo x();
```

declares a function that returns a `Foo`. This is knows as the most vexing parse.