# Different sort methods with template collection

Tags: c++, list, sorting, templates

I sorry if similar question already exists on this forum, if you could, give me the link.

I have a template class

```
template<typename type>
class DoublyLinkedList {};
```

And I want to have Sort method in it.

```
template<typename type>
class DoublyLinkedList
{
public:

void Sort(){}

};
```

But list is template so it can contains different types. So how I can create methods for all types that I foresee? I tried in this way:

```
template<typename type>
class DoublyLinkedList
{
public:

void DoublyLinkedList<int>::Sort(){}
void DoublyLinkedList<string>::Sort(){} 

};
```

But it's wrong. Please help.

Comment: You can do it like how [`std::list::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) does it.

Comment: Just use standard C++ containers. And Stack Overflow is not a "forum".

Comment: @ChristianHackl So, It's not possible to do this? I want to have own implementations.

Comment: I know I can possible do it in one method and next recognize type of list, but I ask about two methods.

Comment: @Michael: Of course it's possible. See @NathanOliver's comment. Do it like `std::list` does and allow users to provide a functor which defaults to `std::less`. But it's a completely uninteresting thing to do, because it reinvents the wheel and will be a solution inferior to `std::list`, with not much to do about other than throwing it away and using `std::list` instead.

Comment: There is another issue to deal with since C++ 11, not having a default allocator. Visual Studio 2015 changed std::list::sort from a bottom up merge sort using a small (25) array of lists to a slower top down merge sort that only uses the iterators. You can read more about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622430/stdlistsort-why-the-sudden-switch-to-top-down-strategy). Note that it is faster to copy a linked list to a vector, sort the vector and copy back, than it is to use std::list::sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the standard library generally deals with this problem is to allow users to specify their own compare functions. You can add a templated parameter that users of your type can use to provide a Compare function, like [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) does. In the implementation of sort, you assume that `comparer` is a function that compares two elements of the list and returns rather or not the first should be before the second.

```
#include <string>
template<typename type>
class DoublyLinkedList
{
public:
    template<class Comp>
    void Sort(Comp comparer);

};

void foo(DoublyLinkedList<std::string> & list)
{
    // Sort list by length of strings
    list.Sort([](const std::string p_left, const std::string p_right){
        return p_left.size() < p_right.size();
    });
}
```

Comment: I would default `compare` to `std::less<type>` just so you do not always have to provide a functor.

Comment: Your code looks pretty clear and proffesional, what do you think about this?
http://pastebin.com/6rSJfF4Z 
I know that this code is bad.

Comment: @Michael That approach will not work in practice . It will only work as long as your supported types have compatible interfaces. That means will only be able to do things to your `type` that works for `int`, `std::string` and *all* other types you choose to support. Remember that even if only one of your branches is taken, they all have to compile for all `type` you support. For example, you couldn't access the characters in the case of `string` because when you tried to instantiate with `int` it would fail to find an `operator[]` for the type `int`.

Comment: @Michael I've modified your example to demonstrate why it can't work. [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/4zSmXDws)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ok, thanks! Can you tell me what I must do in Sort() method with that lambda to sort int's? If I have that lambda as parameter:
http://pastebin.com/DAVjCqWP And I don't know how to use it in Sort().

Comment: @Michael Whichever sort algorithm you are using, it will at one point compare elements. Wherever it would compare two elements (like `x < y`) change it to use the lamdba (like this `comparer(x, y)`).